# No WebApplicationContext found exception for spring validator program

Tags: java

I created a spring mvc project to understand how spring validator works. I am getting an exception in my index.jsp page as " No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?". What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml` to load configuration files.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have added that and I got another error "BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext". For that I added                                                           
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>. But for that I am getting error in web.xml as referenced file contains error for xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"